# "Could not build the application for the simulator." "Error launching application on iPhone 11."

Tags: android, ios, xcode, flutter

I need some help, by accidentally think I deleted some flutter framework, and now I keep getting this error every time I want to launch my app on the IOS simulator through Android Studio.

I have updated the pods and I did change the pod.lock file but nothing seems to be working. Please could someone assist me?

```
Xcode's output:
↳
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further output
    CompileC /Users/joshuachase/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bhfxndfyrvpnssfyeliwkcyzjvoz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/image_picker.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FLTImagePickerPlugin.o /Users/joshuachase/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_picker-0.6.7+4/ios/Classes/FLTImagePickerPlugin.m normal x86_64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:26: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
    class PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:44: Error: Type 'DiagnosticableMixin' not found.
    abstract class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:88:7: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
    class PictureStream with DiagnosticableMixin {
          ^
    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:192:16: Error: The type 'DiagnosticableMixin' can't be mixed in.
    abstract class PictureStreamCompleter with DiagnosticableMixin {
                   ^
    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:167:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
        super.debugFillProperties(properties);
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:171:30: Error: The method 'toStringShort' isn't defined for the class 'PictureStreamCompleter'.
     - 'PictureStreamCompleter' is from 'package:flutter_svg/src/picture_stream.dart' ('../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart').
    Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'toStringShort'.
          ifPresent: _completer?.toStringShort(),
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_svg-0.17.4/lib/src/picture_stream.dart:266:11: Error: Superclass has no method named 'debugFillProperties'.
        super.debugFillProperties(description);
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Comment: Did you try to run `flutter clean`?

Comment: If nothing happened, try to upgrade flutter-svg version to latest. Maybe this will help https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/413

Comment: This didn't work and I have upgraded to the latest version.

Comment: Try `flutter build ios` command, does it get the same error?

Comment: Exact same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the device and erase all the settings of the simulator and try to run .xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj

Comment: Okay I completed the first step, how would I run .xcworkspace in Android Studio? Sorry very new